# Query method in Spring Data JPA for relation @ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have entities `User` and `Conversation`with relation `@ManyToMany` between them:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {
    ...
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="USER_CONVERSATION",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "conversation_id"))
    Set<Conversation> conversations = new HashSet<>();
    ...
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONVERSATION")
public class Conversation {
    ...
    ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "conversations", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    ...
    ...
}
```

And I want to receive all Conversations that have a given user list. I tried something like this:

```
public interface ConversationRepository extends JpaRepository<Conversation, Long> {

    List<Conversation> findAllConversationsByUsers(List<User> users);
```

but I get an error with message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List pl.teamvi.project.repositories.ConversationRepository.findAllConversationsByUsers(java.util.List)! Operator SIMPLE_PROPERTY on users requires a scalar argument, found interface java.util.List in method public abstract java.util.List pl.teamvi.project.repositories.ConversationRepository.findAllConversationsByUsers(java.util.List).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1114) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.repositories(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java:212) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3b0aabb.CGLIB$repositories$51(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3b0aabb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4b18e8f9.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3b0aabb.repositories(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 142 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List pl.teamvi.project.repositories.ConversationRepository.findAllConversationsByUsers(java.util.List)! Operator SIMPLE_PROPERTY on users requires a scalar argument, found interface java.util.List in method public abstract java.util.List pl.teamvi.project.repositories.ConversationRepository.findAllConversationsByUsers(java.util.List).
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 163 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Operator SIMPLE_PROPERTY on users requires a scalar argument, found interface java.util.List in method public abstract java.util.List pl.teamvi.project.repositories.ConversationRepository.findAllConversationsByUsers(java.util.List).
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.throwExceptionOnArgumentMismatch(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:177) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.validate(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:153) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 189 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way to write this query without using the `@Query` annotation?

And why if I change method to:

```
List<Conversation> findAllConversationsByUsers(User users);
```

I don't have any errors? `Users` is `Set`, not single element, so what that query doing?

Comment: It depends on what the query is supposed to do: get all the conversations which have *at least* one of the given users, or get the conversations which have *all* the given users, or get the conversations that have *exactly* the given users (no more, no less). But anyway, you shouldn't be afraid of using Query. It's the right thing to do in most cases.

Comment: I need the conversations that have exacly the given users.

Comment: Then you'll need to write a query, with a subquery. It should find all the conversations which have a total number of users equal to the number of users of the conversation that belong to the given list.

Comment: Could you give any advice to create that query? I stall have problem with it.

Comment: This should work: `select c from Conversation c where size(c.users) = (select count(u2.id) from Conversation c2 join c.users u where c2.id = c.id and u2 in :users)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and to solve it, I added the "In" suffix at the end of the method. Something like:

```
List<Conversation> findAllConversationsByUsersIn(List<User> users);
```

Comment: okay, and what about the case where I want to have an exact match? Do I have to write a query or is there also some repository keyword available for that purpose?

Comment: @monslgnore Exact match for a list? Or a single value?

Comment: exact match for a list; so only return a entity if all objects contained in list parameter are also contained in entities list attribute

Comment: @monsIgnore I don't know any keyword which could be used. If the list has fixed size and it is short, I would use "item1 = ?1 and ...". Because of simplicity. If the list has variable size, I would use Specification Api. https://dimitr.im/writing-dynamic-queries-with-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing so complicated you can add `OrderByUsers` to your method and remove the arguments. so you should have something like `List<Conversation> findAllByOrderByUsers();` and the get the result you want.
Also **note that `By` is to replace Conversations**